# Efficient way to eliminate redundant bounding boxes in character recognition algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, ocr

I'm studying how different binarization algorithms can be applied simultaneously to improve character segmentation for OCR systems.
Essentially, I apply a number of different algorithms with different parameters and use CCA to extract candidate blobs from each of them individually. The idea is that different algorithms detect different characters in the image, and the combination of them all should produce more accurate results.
The output is something like the image below:

[image: example]

```
# Where each color represents the result of a different binarization algo and 
# all bboxes are stored in the same array in format (topleft, bottomright) 
boxes = [box1,box2,...,box_n]
```

What I would like to do now is eliminate redundant bounding boxes before sending the candidate regions to the recognition stage (something like non maximum suppression in ML algorithms, except I don't have confidence scores). Is there an efficient way to do it that wouldn't require me having to iterate over every possible pair of boxes?
Speed is an important factor since I'm working with Python and it I would like it to be viable for real time  analysis.

This experiment is based on the article:
*Best Combination of Binarization Methods for License Plate Character Segmentation*
by Youngwoo Yoon, Kyu‐Dae Ban, Hosub Yoon, Jaeyeon Lee, Jaehong Kim

Comment: So are you essentially trying to do a fast cluster analysis on the given bounding box coordinates?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: Are all of your bounding boxes the same size (or approximately the same size)? Because if so, you can represent each box by its central point, and then just use something like PCA to find redundancies. In fact, your main task is to reduce the problem to a simple cluster analysis problem, and then you can ask on [Stats.SE] about the best algorithm to use.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Not necessarily. There are cases where partial boxes are a thing. When one of the binarization algorithms gets only the bottom half of a number, for example. Not sure how I would treat these cases if I went with that approach

Comment: Hm... Are those partial boxes to be considered correct? And should they be considered duplicates of a full box around the same glyph? Because if you want to consider them as distinct from the proper overlaps, then the method I mentioned should still work, given a sufficiently low clustering threshold.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I believe the system's accuracy would benefit from including those boxes as correct. At least in the cases where the only detection for a certain character was a partial one. A partial detection is better than none, and it would make it possible for me to potentially detect the character with some post-processing  techniques even if not all of it was detected

Comment: If you want to get rid of exact duplicates, you can just sort all the boxes (using e.g. the key (top, left, bottom, right)): this will place all duplicates into a single contiguous block, and you can easily discard all except the first in each such block.  If you want to consider two boxes equivalent even if their co-ordinates differ by a small amount, say 10 pixels, I would instead sort by the same key but with each element of it divided by 10 and rounded down to the nearest integer; repeat this, but with each co-ord first offset by 5 to find edge cases missed by the first run.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That sounds like a pretty fast method (you should make it an answer!), except that it would mean a lot of trial and error before OP could settle on the right pixel threshold to use - not to mention that it would not be robust to differing amounts of variance between duplicate boxes.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky: Thanks.  Indeed this method would not be suitable if the threshold for equivalence can vary throughout the image (I would have thought this would not happen in this application, but who knows -- the OP is not clear on quite a few details like this).  No time to right a properly fleshed-out answer I'm afraid...